# $merge: How to return merged documents after $merge pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Please Help!, I have two collection called `coll1` and `coll2`. I want to update `coll2` on the basis of `coll1` field and return updated docs from `coll2`

```
coll1 :[{"_id":"some_unique_id1", "plan":{"type":"premium"}},
          {"_id":"some_unique_id2", "plan":{"type":"free"}}]

coll2 :[{"_id":"some_unique_id3", "user_id":"some_unique_id1", "eligible":false}]
```

if user has premium plan I want to set `eligible: true` in `coll2` and return the updated document only from `coll2`.

What I have done is updating the `coll2` but not returning the updated documents.
This is my sample code

```
let data = await db.collection("coll1").aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    "plan.type": "premium"
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    eligible: true
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0, user_id: "$_id", eligible: 1
                }
            },
            {
                $merge: {
                    into: "coll2",
                    on: ["user_id"],
                    whenMatched: "merge",
                }
            }

    ]).toArray();
console.log(data)
```

I am not able to pull this off. How can I do this? Can I use `$function` in the `$merge` pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

From [MongoDB document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#replace-documents---merge--vs-replace-collection---out-),

> $merge can replace an existing document in the output collection if the aggregation results contain a document or documents that match based on the on specification. As such, $merge can replace all documents in the existing collection if the aggregation results include matching documents for all existing documents in the collection and you specify "replace" for whenMatched.

I think from this perspective, the aggregation result being returned should be expected, as it is the "to-be" document in the replacement.

For your case, you may first $lookup the whole coll2 document, updating `eligible` to true. Then do a $replaceRoot followed by a final merge.

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZKWnKKgYxsR) for your reference.

Comment: Yeah I tried but still not returning the data. It's returning until we don't have `$merge`. But after `$merge` pipeline it's returning `empty array []`. Thankyou for your reply and time.

Comment: Can you verify if your coll2 collection is successfully updated? From your provided example, it should be working

Comment: Yes, It's updating but not returning the modified documents from `coll2`.

Comment: Hey ManiKantTiwari and @ray did you find a solution? My aggregation pipeline is also returning an empty array. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. It is not possible. You will have to do another query.

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/is-it-possible-to-merge-and-return/133337

MongoDB support team says:

> That’s not possible right now. If you just want the results, just
> execute all the stages in the aggregation pipeline before the $merge
> stage. But if you want it to be outputted into another collection
> you’ll need that extra query.

For more details look at the link above.